# Dynamically get/set store value in svelte from input

Tags: svelte

I want to do this, **TLDR**:

```js
/** This is the Input.svelte */

<script>
  export let identifier;

  import * as state from "./store"
</script>

<input bind:value={$state[identifier]} />
```

Longer story, I've defined a load of input fields in a list of objects, which I then iterate over and put on the `<Input field />` component... but I need to save these values in a store to then continuously update a "Preview panel".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works more or less as is. The only problem is the state import/export. If you import via `*` that object is not going to be a store, but you can just export a single store instead.

`store.js`

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export const state = writable({});
```

`Input.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import { state } from "./store";
  export let identifier;
</script>
<input bind:value={$state[identifier]} />
```

Example usage:

```html
<script>
    import Input from './Input.svelte';
    import { state } from './store';
</script>

<Input identifier="value1"/>
<Input identifier="value2"/>

<p>Value1: {$state.value1}</p>
<p>Value1: {$state.value2}</p>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/df3a734ba3d8429d952f94ed519769d9?version=3.47.0)

The `identifier` could be set dynamically as well, e.g. in an `each` block.

[REPL using `each`](https://svelte.dev/repl/db1a2b4ee2754307a80fd02b65a6e231?version=3.47.0)

---

PS: You might want to pass in the store as a property or use a [context](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) instead of a global import. That way it is more transparent where the state is coming from and where it is being used. It also makes testing components easier.